# Jsoup connect doesn't work correctly when there is an absolute link?

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup, href

I'm using Jsoup to get html from web sites. for example I have the links in my HTML page look like this:

```
String url="http://kitchen.sayidaty.net/node/8544/كوكيزبالشوفان/حلويات";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

this link parse NOTHING and throws IOException, but when I open this link manually in browser and take it back to my code it get changed and works fine ! like this :

```
String url="http://kitchen.sayidaty.net/node/8544/%D9%83%D98%B2-%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA#ingredients";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

is there any way to get the absolute link (the second one) , I tried this but same result :'(

```
link.attr("abs:href")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing has to do with the charset specification http protocol handle when you do transactions like POST and GET. You must use a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format (For more information about HTML form encoding, consult the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/)).

In your case, for this to work you have to use [Android URLencoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder), but only at the end of the address you want to use, to avoid problems. So transform:

```
String url="http://kitchen.sayidaty.net/node/8544/كوكيزبالشوفان/حلويات";
```

Into:

```
String auxUrl= URLEncoder.encode("كوكيزبالشوفان/حلويات", "utf-8");
String url="http://kitchen.sayidaty.net/node/8544/" + auxUrl;
```

Then proceed with your

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Comment: @SundosAltamimi glad to see it worked. Please, check my answer as the correct one. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: My friend, please, at the top left of my answer, check the green "V" to sinalize my answer is correct. This way you improve my reputation here on StackaOverflow, something that works as a "salary" for our work and time invested on the benefit of others, helping people like you with questions and doubts. Please consider the time and attention people invested on you. Thank you. Best wishes.